# Update an enum type

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, enums

This is my Code:

```
public function enUser($userID) {
    try {
        $userStatus = "Y";
        $tokenCode = "";
        $sql = ('UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus = ? AND tokenCode = ? WHERE userID = ?');

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $userStatus);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $tokenCode);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $userID);
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

[This is my enum in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXP68.png)

I have try more to edit it. But in database always appear nothing. I mean in the field 'userStatus' after running the update script, its just value like "" (empty). Can any one help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You update must be:

```
'UPDATE tbl_users SET userStatus = ?, tokenCode = ? WHERE userID = ?
```

See the comma instead of `AND`

And make sure that `$userID` exists in your DB